# Android: How do I initialize View and Canvas?

Tags: java, android

I need to initialize View and Canvas for the project I'm working on, but after an hour or so or searching, I can't figure out what to make them equal to.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
 public class DisplayMap extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        try {
            displayMap();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SlickException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void displayMap() throws IOException, SlickException {
        loadWorld("assets/World.tmx");
    }

    public void loadWorld(String path) throws IOException {
        View view = ?????;
        Canvas canvas = ?????;

        //World loading goes here
    }
    }
```

So, can anybody please suggest me how to initialize View and Canvas? Or am I going about this in the completely wrong way?

Comment: Do you have a parser for the TMX map?

Comment: No, I couldn't get any to work/couldn't figure them out. So I'm making my own parser and modeling it off one from a C# project of mine.

Comment: if you have ur customized view u can initialize like View view=new View(Context,AttributeSet); setContentView(view);

Comment: Thank you. But now, how do I initialize AttributeSet?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a custom view that loads the map, and then use the custom view in your activity.

In `TMXView.java`:

```
public class TMXView extends View {
  public TMXView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // Load map
  }

  public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
     // Draw the map on the canvas
  }
}
```

In `onCreate` of your activity:

```
 View view = new TMXView(this);
 setContentView(view);
```

For more information, refer to my talk on custom components: http://www.sqisland.com/talks/android-custom-components/

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you think you could look at this other question of mine? We are having trouble figuring it out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105504/android-how-can-i-overlay-this-level-on-the-background